# How to reset permissions in drupal 7 manually through mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, permissions, reset

I have developed a site in drupal 7 and forget its admin password. Now when I request for new password it sent me a link to "one time" login screen. When I click on "LOGIN" button it takes me to following page where it is stated that: "You are not authorized to access this page."

```
http://somedomain.com/?q=user/1/edit&pass-reset-token=K33tsqRwVOhtt0om0H9hGa4TfUGeyQCIbvCA7qV-2tk
```

Its my first site in drupal and I believe I modified permissions for pages is basic cause of the problem. Is there a way I can reset permissions without loosing any data through mysql or some thing like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your password without being logged in to Drupal but not from MySQL alone. Check out the instructions in the documentation at https://drupal.org/node/1023428

Comment: Yes you are right about resetting pw but there is some problem with permissions. Can you please suggest how to reset permisions in DP7

Comment: User 1 has all permissions no matter what. If you want to change permissions for other users you can log in as user 1 and edit the permissions settings.